# Xamarin: A public field without getXXX()/setXXX() lost its generic when binding a jar lib

Tags: jar, xamarin

In jar:

```
public List<CloudPoiInfo> poiList;
```

but Xamarin generated the code as `System.Collections.IList poiList`
which `System.Collections.Generic.IList<Com.Baidu.Mapapi.Cloud.CloudPoiInfo> myClassList` is right.

I've tried

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.baidu.mapapi.cloud']/class/field[@type-generic-aware='java.util.List&lt;com.baidu.mapapi.cloud.CloudPoiInfo&gt;']" name="type">System.Collections.Generic.IList&lt;Com.Baidu.Mapapi.Cloud.CloudPoiInfo&gt;</attr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it:

Metadata.xml

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.baidu.mapapi.cloud']/class[@name='CloudSearchResult']/field[@name='poiList']"/>
```

{project}/Additions/CloudSearchResult.cs

```
using Android.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Com.Baidu.Mapapi.Cloud
{
    public partial class CloudSearchResult : BaseSearchResult
    {
    static IntPtr poiList_jfieldId;

    // Metadata.xml XPath field reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.baidu.mapapi.cloud']/class[@name='CloudSearchResult']/field[@name='poiList']"
    [Register("poiList")]
    public global::System.Collections.Generic.IList<CloudPoiInfo> PoiListX
    {
        get
        {
        if (poiList_jfieldId == IntPtr.Zero)
            poiList_jfieldId = JNIEnv.GetFieldID(class_ref_2, "poiList", "Ljava/util/List;");
        IntPtr __ret = JNIEnv.GetObjectField(Handle, poiList_jfieldId);
        return global::Android.Runtime.JavaList<CloudPoiInfo>.FromJniHandle(__ret, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
        }
        set
        {
        if (poiList_jfieldId == IntPtr.Zero)
            poiList_jfieldId = JNIEnv.GetFieldID(class_ref_2, "poiList", "Ljava/util/List;");
        IntPtr native_value = global::Android.Runtime.JavaList<CloudPoiInfo>.ToLocalJniHandle(value);
        JNIEnv.SetField(Handle, poiList_jfieldId, native_value);
        JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(native_value);
        }
    }

    internal static new IntPtr java_class_handle_2;
    internal static new IntPtr class_ref_2
    {
        get
        {
        return JNIEnv.FindClass("com/baidu/mapapi/cloud/CloudSearchResult", ref java_class_handle_2);
        }
    }
    }

    public abstract partial class BaseSearchResult : Java.Lang.Object
    {
    }

    public partial class CloudPoiInfo : Java.Lang.Object
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics in Java and C# are very different so the IList without generics is actually correct. This is due to type erasure on Java side.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

> Generics are checked at compile-time for type-correctness. The generic
>   type information is then removed in a process called type erasure. For
>   example, List will be converted to the non-generic type List,
>   which ordinarily contains arbitrary objects. The compile-time check
>   guarantees that the resulting code is type-correct.
>
> Consequent to type erasure, type parameters cannot be determined at
>   run-time. For example, when an ArrayList is examined at runtime, there
>   is no general way to determine whether, before type erasure, it was an
>   ArrayList or an ArrayList.

Comment: Thx, but I need this generic.The jar is a third-party one and it's proGruaded.. Can I fix this issue?

Comment: What kind of use case you have for the generic? Use from your code? Can't you just create a wrapper around it with a cast to IList<T>?

Comment: I attempt do cast using (IList<CloudPoiInfo>) poiList, then vs called the uncaught ClassCastException..I deleted the dir 'bin' in my project and built the project (not re-built), the code goes well..